# Using Fluent Assertion It is possible to attach the result of an assertion to a custom logger

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to determine the result of an assertion in order to use the output for reporting, something like this:

```
ProblemResolution().Should().Match("easy");

Logger(Assertion.Result());
```

I also tried by creating an extension, but I can't figure out how to "extract" the result, in case that there is any

```
 Execute.Assertion
            .BecauseOf(because)
            .ForCondition(Subject.Equals(str))
            .FailWith($"{because} {Subject} expected to be equals to ${str} but found {Subject}");
        return new AndConstraint<FluentAsserts>(this);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can [wrap](https://fluentassertions.com/introduction#assertion-scopes) the assertion code in an `AssertionScope` and then call `Discard` to get the failure messages and prevent the scope from throwing the failure exception at the end of the `using` block.

Comment: Does that answer your question?